# Build an array with previous three months from current month in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I showing a report which brings three months data from current month. For example, this month is june so it brings, April, May and June data.

I want to build an array in javascript/angularjs which gives me the previous three months from current date like this:

```
$scope.montharray = [
{
monthname: "All",
Monthnumber: "4,5,6"
},
{
monthname: "April",
MonthNumber:"4",
},
{
monthname: "May",
MonthNumber:"5",
},
{
monthname: "June",
MonthNumber:"6",
}
]
```

Can someone help me how i can achieve to get the rolling three months array like this?

TIA

Comment: Start here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 1):

You will need an array to look up the month names. Work out the current month with a new date. Use Array.from to create your array. Make sure to % mod by 12 to wrap back to January if you go over 12.

```js
const monthNames = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];
const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

const monthArray = Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, index) =>
  index === 0
    ? { monthname: 'All', monthNumber: `${currentMonth},${(currentMonth + 1) % 12},${(currentMonth + 2) % 12}` }
    : { monthName: monthNames[(currentMonth + index - 2) % 12], monthNumber: `${(currentMonth + index - 1) % 12}` }
);

console.log(monthArray);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what is the best way to the previous three months from current month, without breaking when it comes to December and January ?

Comment: Add 12 then mod 12 so that -1 becomes 11 etc.